# Does a 14 day visa for Dubai start on date of issue or date of arrival?

Tags: visas, dubai, uae, day-counting

I just got a Dubai visa but I am confused. The visa was issued on the 3rd of February and expires on the 16th of February. I am travelling on the 12th of February.

Does the 14 days visa start reading when I get there or do I have to leave before the 16th?

Comment: Can you clarify what visa you have?  A scan with personal information redacted would be useful.

Answer (score 10):

From what I understand, there are two different limits:

- the duration of validity, which starts on the day of issue, and limits when you can enter the country
- the duration of stay, which starts on the day of entry, and limits how long you can stay.

Confusingly, service visas have the same 14-day duration for both (but other types of visas often have different durations).

As far as I understand it, you can arrive within 14 days of the date of issue, and stay 14 days from the date of entry. However this is not made very explicit on any of the government sites I have seen, so you may want to inquire with whomever issued that visa for you for confirmation.

Answer (score 5):

From the information you’ve given it looks like you have a Short Term Visit Single Entry – Service visa. This visa is non-extendable, valid for 14 days from the date of issue. So you have to leave by 16th. 
http://www.dubaivisa.net/uae/duration14days.html

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to stay only for the duration of the validity which in your case is 16th Feb.

The visa is not linked to your days of travel. So it doesn't matter when you arrive there you have to leave Dubai by 16th Feb

Answer (score 1):

I think @jcaron is right here. That said, if this is a visa (Not a permit to remain in the country) issued outside of the country, then in most case expire date means the day the visa becomes invalid, thus you have to use it on or before that day. On arrival (Port of Entry) the immigration office determines how long you stay for the visit, if it wasn't explicitly stated on the visa. This is different for country to country as well. Some country have fixed time for everyone, some have time based on the country of citizenship, while others it the officer that determines based on but not limited to the following criteria;
*country of citizenship
*purpose of visit
*general demeanor
*date on return ticket.
That said, I if we see a sample of the visa could give us more light into this matter. I hope that helps, cheers.